# How to exclude files present in the mapped directory when Publishing the artifacts in Azure CI/CD?

Tags: azure-devops, dynamics-crm, cicd

I am new to Azure CICD pipelines and I am trying to export the CRM solutions using Build pipeline in azure devops using Power Platform Task. There is a requirement to keep the exported solution from build pipeline to Azure repos. (which I am doing it from command line using tf vc)
I am able to export the solution successfully but the issue is when I publish the artifacts it publishes every file present in the mapped folder. (mapped a directory in Azure repos where all the solution backups are kept)

I see that azure agents copies all the files present in the mapped directory and stores in agent directory. The problem is the mapped directory contains all the backup files of CRM Solutions. I found some articles where it was mentioned to cloak the directory so that the files will not be included in azure agent. But if I cloak the directory then I am not able to check-in the exported solution from command line.

So, I was wondering if there is any way to exclude all files present in the mapped directory and still able to check-in the exported file to that directory using command line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a .artifactignore file to filter out paths of files that you don't wish to be published as part of the process.

Documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/reference/artifactignore?view=azure-devops)